# Can't complete "A Night to Remember"

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been playing Skyrim and have came across what I think is a bug.

During the quest "A Night to Remember" I have found two items missing. When I went to rescue Gleda the Goat from the giant neither Gleda nor the giant was there. There was just an arrow pointing at the ground, so I just returned to the farmer and gave him money.

When I went to collect the wedding ring from a cabin in some woods I killed the witch person outside but when I searched the cabin there was no ring. I also searched around the cabin, the witch and the chest next to the door and I don't want to have to give away 2000 gold. I've tried reloading, waiting, sleeping and can't think of anything else to do.

Does anyone know how to get the ring?

Comment: Not directly relevant to your question  but this quest seems to be really buggy - I never did half of it. After I got drunk I just intimidated Adrienne, who told me where to find Sam. I went to the dungeon, cleared it and then the quest finished. She had been talking about the wedding but I never did anything about it :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very odd - I found the wedding ring on the witch myself, so it does sound like a glitch. Unfortunately as an Xbox user you can't abuse the console into solving the problem.

If I remember correctly if your speech is high enough, you should be able to persuade/intimidate Ysolda into telling you the next location for the quest. This looks to be your only option if you don't want to pay.

Comment: i tried pursuading her but it didn't work so i just payed but thanks for the advice:)

Answer (score 0):

I found the ring on the witch.  The item name is "Wedding Ring".